# In flutter, Is it possible to use Android or iOS widget, just like react native

Tags: widget, flutter

As we know, flutter can call Android or iOS api by plugin, I had written some widgets, Android and iOS native widgets, can I use those widgets in flutter, just like in react native. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by native widgets? `App Widgets` of android and `Today's extensions` of IOS?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is NO

Flutter completely bypasses the iOS and Android OEM control pipeline and draws the entire screen as a Skia canvas, with its own dart UI widgets.

There is no mechanism to mix the flutter canvas with OEM controls

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

With https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AndroidView-class.html (Android) and https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UiKitView-class.html (iOS)

Google is using this two Widgets to render WebViews and Maps on those platforms.
See: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter and https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

It is definitely not easy to use, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `App Widgets` that are shown on android desktop, then it is possible to implement such `Widgets` with native code and use it with flutter.

I'll not completely deny that it is not possible to bridge between native widget and flutter's dart code, but I can say the possibility is yet to be discovered.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mhm1K8-Fh451vAEryK05RG54Iwp2ETp6) is the simple `App Widget` created natively and used with flutter.

[image: Gif image]

If you wanted to look into the source code, and build app from source. [Here](https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_home_screen_widget_example) it is.

Hope that helped!